# Matching String Wrapped In Symbol For Regex Replace

Tags: regex, wordpress, syntax-highlighting

I'm trying to figure out how to implement Regex on my WordPress blog.

**The Problem**

I'd like to replace certain content with some inline styles, and I'm using Regex to accomplish this.

My idea is as follows: find the string wrapped in a particular symbol, i.e. "~string~" and dynamically replace this with a span that has a particular class.

I'm going for a similar effect to SO's inline `code` highlighting feature, but instead of using backticks, I'm using "~" as my symbol of choice (since WordPress already identifies "`" as code).

**Quick Example**

*Original Text*

`This is a demo paragraph with a wrapped string ~here~, with another string ~~here~~.`

*After Regex Replacement*

`This is a demo paragraph with a wrapped string <span class="classOne">here</span>, with another string <span class="classTwo">here</span>.`

**What I'm Struggling With**

The regex I'm using is this: /~(.*?)~/, and it's working fine for finding strings such as "~demo~", but I'm not sure how to extend it to be able to find strings with multiple delimiters, like: "~~demo~~".

The tricky part for me is that it needs to distinguish between just one "~" versus two of them because I'd like to assign different replacements to each result.

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is not a problem, just use alternation, [`~~([\s\S]*?)~~|~([^~]*)~`](https://regex101.com/r/Liejbl/1). Then process each capture as needed.

Comment: Or, `~~([\s\S]*?)~~(?!~)|~([^~]*)~`

Comment: That's fantastic, thank you so much for the tips!

Comment: Please  check [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65581683/3832970).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```php
~~([\s\S]*?)~~(?!~)|~([^~]*)~
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Liejbl/2). Details:

- `~~([\s\S]*?)~~(?!~)` - `~~`, then a capturing group #1 matching any zero or more chars but as few as possible, and then a `~~` substring not followed with another `~` char
- `|` - or
- `~([^~]*)~` - a `~`, then a capturing group #2 matching zero or more chars other than `~`, and then a `~`

If you use it in PHP, you may use the pattern with `preg_replace_callback` where you may define separate replacement logic when a specific capturing group is matched.

See a [PHP demo](https://3v4l.org/graet):

```php
$html = 'This is a demo paragraph with a wrapped string ~here~, with another string ~~here~~.';
echo preg_replace_callback('/~~([\s\S]*?)~~(?!~)|~([^~]*)~/', function ($m) {
    return !empty($m[1]) ? '<span class="classTwo">' . $m[1] . '</span>' : '<span class="classOne">' . $m[2] . '</span>';
},$html);
// => This is a demo paragraph with a wrapped string <span class="classOne">here</span>, with another string <span class="classTwo">here</span>.
```

Comment: This is *exactly* what I was looking for, thank you so much! I'm new to PHP, so I didn't realize I could use `preg_replace_callback()` in that way. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

To make it little more generic, you can try this (~+)([^~]+?)(~+). This would need an additional check on the number of characters present in the 1st or the 3rd grouping which matches (~). Based on the number of characters take a decision in code for classOne, classTwo, classThree etc...

Comment: That's great, I'll try that out too. I appreciate the help!